# Django get months from models.DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, datetime

Is it possible to filter a models.DateTimeField but only get the month in the filter object?

The field is:

```
time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
```

When I filter it, this is what I get:

> [datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 22, 15, 2, 48, 867473, tzinfo=),
>   datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 22, 15, 4, 22, 618675, tzinfo=),
>   datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 22, 15, 5, 20, 939593, tzinfo=)]

The filter returns 3 rows, but clearly there is too much information. I only require the months, and maybe the year.

How can I achieve this?

Any help or direction would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using django 1.10.x there is [`Extract`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#extract) db function

```
from django.db.models.functions import Extract

months = MyModel.objects.annotate(month_stamp=Extract('time_stamp', 'month')).values_list('month_stamp', flat=True)
```

For django 1.9.x

```
from django.db.models import Func

def Extract(field, date_field='DOW'):
    template = "EXTRACT({} FROM %(expressions)s::timestamp)".format(date_field)
    return Func(field, template=template)

months = MyModel.objects.annotate(month_stamp=Extract('time_stamp', 'month')).values_list('month_stamp', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use propety:

```
Class your_model(models.Model):

    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)

    @property
    def _get_year(self):
        return self.time_stamp.strftime("%Y-%m")

    year = property(_get_year) #EDIT
```

Comment: 1. If it's a method, it could be called `get_year`, but for a property, just call it `year`.  2. Note that this will only work on instances, not on querysets

Comment: and to query, you do: months = results.values_list('get_year', flat=True)?? | Thanks for the elaboration @wim

Comment: Like I said, it won't work in a queryset.  You have to use a comprehension instead, or change the field.

Comment: @wim How can I change the field to only store current month and year using datetime.datetime?? The default timzone.now is useless in my case.

Comment: @Windsooon when I filter year, I get "Cannot resolve keyword 'year' into field". I suppose as wim said, you can't query property.

Comment: You can't not use property in queryset, because  django filters operate at the database level